# Memsql throws error MemSQL does not support server-side prepared statements

Tags: go, nosql, singlestore

I am trying to execute query in memsql with golang. But i keep getting error.
"MemSQL does not support server-side prepared statements."

I am even using "interpolateParams=true" but still the same error.

```
var Dbmysql, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/memsql?interpolateParams=true") 
tx,err := Dbmysql.Begin()
fmt.Println(err)
stmt, err := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO squareNum VALUES( ?, ? )") // ? = placeholder
fmt.Println(err)

for i:=0;i<1e6;i++{
    _,err = stmt.Exec("test",1)
    log.Println(tx.Rollback())
    fmt.Println(err)
} 

err = tx.Commit()
fmt.Println(err)
```

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear to me. `Prepare` is not supported for MemSQL.

Comment: I know, whats the solution ?  just use db.Query?

Answer (score 1):

In Go's driver, the interpolateParams=true option only applies to things like `Exec("INSERT INTO squareNum VALUES( ?, ? )", 1, 2)` - it doesn't apply to `Prepare()`. So you'll have to stick with the former - just don't use explicit `Prepare()`